# PHP html_entity_decode and HTML <a> tag

Tags: php, xml, html-encode

I am trying to use MediaWiki's API to get articles in XML format and include them on my page. I created a simple code which basically gets the XML representation of an article using `?action=parse&page=Page_Name&format=xml` requests. The code is following:

```
if($_GET["page"]=='') die("Page not specified (possibly direct call)");
$pagename = $_GET["page"];
$handle = @fopen("mediawiki/api.php?action=parse&page=".$pagename."&format=xml", "r");
if ($handle) {
        while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = $buffer.fgets($handle);
        }       
    $buffer = html_entity_decode($buffer);
    /*
    echo $buffer;
    */
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer);
    foreach($xml->parse->children() as $child){
        switch($child->getName()){
            case "text":
                echo $child->asXML()."<br/>";
                break;
            case "categories":
                echo "<h3>Categories this project is related to: </h3><br/>";
                foreach($child->children() as $grandChild){
                    echo $grandChild." | ";
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Now the problem is that I'm getting very strange output. Any `<a name="" href=""></a>` becomes converted to `<a name="" href=""/>` which makes all following text to become a link (I guess since there is not closing tag `</a>`). This is observed both in Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome. I'm suspecting `$buffer = html_entity_decode($buffer);` to cause this problem. Is there a parameter for `html_entity_decode();` I should specify to avoid this? Is it caused by some other error or misuse of `html_entity_decode();` in my code?

(To see the XML output of the Wiki's API, you can try `http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=No_Such_Page&format=xml` with different `page` parameters)

POSSIBLE SOLUTION: I didn't want to go to JSON, as Jordan suggested, so I came up with this solution. I simply moved `html_entity_decode` to the `case "text":` block. So now I have there `echo html_entity_decode($child->asXML())."<br/>";`. Do you think this is feasible enough?

Comment: @Azimuth, there you go! Paste it into the textarea, select it and hit Ctrl-K to indent it all 4 spaces (or in the case of that code, the relevant stuff was already indented 4 spaces, so I just copied and pasted it)

Comment: `<a name="" href=""></a>` is an empty element, which in XML can be self-closed to `<a name="" href=""/>`.

Comment: @Dominic is that the browsers' problem then? Because as I wrote both FF and Chrome output it so that all text becomes a link...
Thanks for putting the code

Comment: are you sure html_entity_decode is causing this? my guess is simplexml_load_string would cause this as its finding nodes with no children.

if you are concerned do more work inside the $grandChild loop (check for <a> tags and work from there)

Comment: @Janek the problem is occurring in the `text` XML child not `categories`.
This is what the browser gets: http://pastebin.ca/1711171
This is the original XML: http://pastebin.ca/1711175
so as you see the first `</a>` disappears which causes the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with `html_entity_decode()`. The problem is that SimpleXML is treating the contents of the `<text>` element as XML instead of text. By default, SimpleXML compresses empty elements (`<a></a>` to `<a />`). One way to get around this is to import the SimpleXML object into a DOM object, and use the `LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG` option when [saving the output](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php). The problem with this option is that any `<br />` elements will be output as `<br></br>`.

The simpler alternative is to use a different response format from the API. I would suggest using the `json` response format and use the [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/json_decode) function to parse the response.

Answer (score 1):

That's not strange output, that's valid XML.  When you have an empty tag, XML lets you use a short closing syntax that's not always valid in HTML or XHTML

```
<foo></foo>
<foo />
```

The `html_entity_decode();` function converts html entities, such as

```
&gt; converts to
>
```

You'll need to post-process your xml fragment and convert it into proper HTML.  The easiest way to do this is with the `DomDocument` API.

```
$foo = new DomDocument();
$foo->loadHtml('<p> Testing <a href="" /> </p>');   
echo $foo->saveHtml();
```

This will take an XML fragment, and convert it into and HTML document, which includes fixing all the self closing tags.  You'll still need to parse out stuff in the `<body/>`, but that's a lot easier than fixing all the self closing tags yourself.